# How to find the barycenter/center of mass of this 2d shape without calculation?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, centroid

I am given this shape (or any similar shape which is symmetrical). How can I determine the barycenter without calculating anything?

[image]

My thought intuitively is, that the center should be at C, since it is denser around the middle (thus pulling the center of mass towards it. However I'm not sure. Is there a smart and quick way to deal with such shapes and finding the barycenter?

the "exercise" is to estimate where the center of mass / barycenter is going to be , the choices which are given are : ABCD and E (none of these, which is only really ever the case if its really obviously not ABCD)

it is meant to be solved in under 1 minute , so there is no time to draw triangles, or calculate integrals , how would one go about quickly estimating the barycenter for such an object?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Sorry, can't be done without more information, probably not without calculating. My intuition says not quite as far right as C. Somewhere between B and C.

Comment: not even if i can draw lines into the figure?

Comment: You could draw lines and then use them to make a rough calculation. Or cut it out of cardboard and see where it balances. Since it's symmetric about the horizontal axis you could balance it on a ruler rather than a point.

Comment: i see, well its a multiple choice question which is supposed to be solved without anything in less than 1 minute so im not sure this is the right way to go about it lol

Comment: Not fair! You withheld information. "Which of these answers is right" is almost certainly an easier question. Presumably there are reasons to reject some of the choices, You're not expected to calculate and match the answer. If you [edit] the question to show us the choices and what you think perhaps we can help. If the choices are A, B, C or D then I would go with C.

Comment: I think $A, B, D$ are obviously wrong, so it must either be $C$ or else a point with no label.

Comment: i mean, what did you think ABCD stood for? lol but OK , and yes, a point with no label is also an option but usually that's not really the solution just from my test 
 taking experience (unless the point is really way far off)

Comment: I didn't think much about ABCD since you didn't tell us this was a test question with multiple choices. You asked about calculating the center of mass without calculating so that's what I thought you wanted to know.

Comment: haha ok, but no,it's a MC question where you have to decide where the barycenter/center of mass lies ; i know how to calculate the barycenter, but i dont see any way to quickly estimate it

Comment: Now you've edited the question so that our discussion is out of date. I've no more to say about it.

Comment: my apologies if you put considerable effort into it already, but it was obvious to me and from my wording that it was a multiple choice question lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the part is homogeneous, the vertical through the barycenter must split the area in two equal parts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your shape is made of cardboard, and ask yourself this question: "where should I hammer a nail so that my shape stays horizontal on the wall, without rotating?". The answer is some point near to C.